# Disable "previous link" in first post and "next link" in last post

Tags: next-post-link, previous-post-link

how can I disable "previous link" in first post and "next link" in last post?
thank you

Comment: ooops sorry... I mean: Disable “previous link” in FIRST post and “next link” in LAST post

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php next_post_link('format', 'link', 'in_same_cat', 'excluded_categories'); ?> 

<?php previous_post_link($format, $link, $in_same_cat = false, $excluded_categories = ''); ?>
```

Comment: not to show the link in this situation is imho the default bahaviour of `next_post_link()` (and 'prev' resp)

Comment: @:Michael sorry friend,i can't get you.will you explain little bit more?'

Comment: your latest edit is nearly what i was talking about: the genuine wordpress functions `next_post_link()` and `previous_post_link()` (singular 'post' not 'posts') don't show for the first and last post, resp.

Comment: @:Michael,thanks for pointing out.am little confused with this [function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_posts_link).

Answer (score 1):

Just use this, no extra functions required:

```
<div class="previous-post"> <?php previous_post_link(' &laquo;%link ') ?> </div>
<div class="next-post"> <?php next_post_link(' %link &raquo; ') ?> </div>
```

Just add this to the single.php, not the index.php. This is the simple way to show in single posts only (this won't show the prev. post link on the last post, on the first post there won't be a next post).